# SQL using DISTINCT with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I currently have 9 columns joined using `INNER JOIN`
but i now want to remove the duplicates from column 1 which is *CIFnumber*.

If i use `DISTINCT` at the top of the query it does not function.

What could I do?

```
select distinct
    c.CIFNumber,c.FirstName,c.Surname,c.FamilyID,a.AccountID,
    b.V‌​aluationAmount,d.NAM‌​E,ad.ID_Number,f.PrP‌​lanner 
from
    CUSTOMERINFORMATIONFILETBL c
inner join ACCOUNTTBL a on c.CIFNumber=a.CIFNumber
inner join BALANCETBL b on a.AccountID=b.AccountID
inner join FAMILYTBL f on c.FamilyID= f.FamilyID
inner join DIVISION d on f.DIVISION=d.ID
inner join ADDRESSTBL ad on c.CIFNumber=ad.CIF 
where
    b.ValuationDate = '2017-09-30' and
    d.name = 'Wealth Management' and
    (
        ad.ID_Number= '' or
        ad.ID_Number is null or
        LEN(ad.ID_Number) < 13
    )
```

Comment: Why not just post your script? No-one wants to write that out by hand in order to answer your question

Comment: I do apologize, i will add it now

Comment: select distinct c.CIFNumber,c.FirstName,c.Surname,c.FamilyID,a.AccountID,b.ValuationAmount,d.NAME,ad.ID_Number,f.PrPlanner

 from CUSTOMERINFORMATIONFILETBL c

 inner join ACCOUNTTBL a on  c.CIFNumber=a.CIFNumber
 inner join BALANCETBL b on a.AccountID=b.AccountID
 inner join FAMILYTBL f on c.FamilyID= f.FamilyID
 inner join DIVISION d on f.DIVISION=d.ID
 inner join ADDRESSTBL ad on c.CIFNumber=ad.CIF


where 
b.ValuationDate = '2017-09-30'
and d.name = 'Wealth Management'
and (ad.ID_Number= '' or ad.ID_Number is null or LEN(ad.ID_Number) < 13)

Comment: Please post the script into your question using the edit functionality. Also please read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Im aware that you are a new user but following the rules specified in that link will definitely save you from being downvoted into oblivion in the future. **EDIT, I have updated your question with the script you provided above.**

Comment: How do you want to remove the duplicates?  Which CFINumber row should remain when there are multiples?

Comment: you need to understand that distinct operates on all the fields so if a CIF has two different firstnames it has to repeat

Comment: Ok so it seems i dont need to remove the duplicates. They can work with the data i have pulled.

Comment: OK CIF is unique to the Firstname & surname

Comment: It's _columns_, not fields...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Your problem is mainly that you want to select all accounts/balances and all adresses for a customer. With four balance records and two addresses for instance you get eight result rows where you see each balance twice and each address four-fold. This may be desired or not. Sometimes it isn't and you want aggregations instead, e.g. a string of the addresses, a string of the account numbers, and the sum of the balances. In that case group by customer and aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT does function - it remove duplicates of the column set in specific SELECT statement. If DISTINCT did't remove duplicates for specific column in your column set it means that you have unique values in other columns.

If you need only one unique value from specific column and don't care about other column values, you can use window function.

```
   select *
   from (
    select c.CIFNumber,c.FirstName,..., 
    row_number() over (partition by c.CIFNumber order by [some logic]) as rn
    from...) as a 
    where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two or more different values in at least one of your columns. If you dont care about some data you can use [TOP 1 WITH TIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql) + [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
select top 1 with ties
            c.CIFNumber,
            c.FirstName,
            c.Surname,
            c.FamilyID,
            a.AccountID,
            b.V‌​aluationAmount,
            d.NAM‌​E,
            ad.ID_Number,
            f.PrP‌​lanner 
from
    CUSTOMERINFORMATIONFILETBL c
inner join ACCOUNTTBL a on c.CIFNumber=a.CIFNumber
inner join BALANCETBL b on a.AccountID=b.AccountID
inner join FAMILYTBL f on c.FamilyID= f.FamilyID
inner join DIVISION d on f.DIVISION=d.ID
inner join ADDRESSTBL ad on c.CIFNumber=ad.CIF 
where
    b.ValuationDate = '2017-09-30' and
    d.name = 'Wealth Management' and
    (
        ad.ID_Number= '' or
        ad.ID_Number is null or
        LEN(ad.ID_Number) < 13
    )
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CIFNumber, c.FirstName, c.Surname, c.FamilyID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

In my example I expect that `c.CIFNumber, c.FirstName, c.Surname, c.FamilyID` are unique.